# Are contact groups totally gone for Marshmallow?

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, 6.0-marshmallow, google-contacts, contact-groups

I own a Sony XZ with Android 6.0.1 Marshmallow and I just upgraded from a 4.4 KitKat phone.

Under Google Contacts you can add each user to one or many groups and these groups were visible under KitKat.  I assumed that would stay the same, but it doesn't seem like it.

I read that since Lollipop this feature was no longer available.  Can anyone support or reject that fact?  Is there any way around it?  Does anyone know **why** Google removed such a useful feature and then only half (Android support) of it?

Comment: It was removed here https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Contacts/+/5f057fa8a0d1be9529024846c9e69b5764078d2c%5E%21/ but I couldn't find why

Comment: When I swipe in from the left in the current Google Contacts app, I see the same labels that I use in the web-based Google Contacts (the current preview version). Nexus 5, Android 6.0.1, https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.contacts Compare the second snapshot in the link that I posted - "Organize your contacts with labels" - you'll see what I mean.

Comment: @bers: Thx! But for whatever reason, it's incompatible with my device, says the Play Store. It can't be the OS Version, since I use 6.0.1 and Contacts requires 5.0 and up. Is it possible that Sony *forces* me to use their Contacts App?

Comment: It's rather that Google forbids you to use their Contacts app, I guess. I remember that incident for the Phone app, but it seems the Contacts app was involved, too: http://www.ubergizmo.com/2015/12/google-stock-android-phone-contacts-app/ The article says "Prior to this [as well as after this], the stock Android apps were only available on Google Nexus devices, Android One handsets, and Google Play Edition devices".